# where can we get documentation for component object model

Tags: vba, com

I want COM documentation if there is any as I want to know all even little things about COM. For example, as a common rule, converting below code for word application

`Documents.Add`

to COM as

`oWord.Documents.Add`

is easy just by adding object variable **oWord**. But how can we know that converting below VBA

`Selection.Font.Color = 16711680`

to below COM

`oWord.Selection.Font.Color := wdColorBlue := 16711680`

How `:= wdColorBlue := 16711680` comes?

I thought it should be either `:= wdColorBlue` or `:= 16711680`. But I couldn't imagine it is `:= wdColorBlue := 16711680`.

Where can we find these little details?

Reference URL: https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/120360-changing-font-type-color-size-with-1-set-of-code-across-all-ms-office-programs/

Comment: The value for blue is `0xFF0000`, its meaning is hardly related to COM, even though it's documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd946077%28v=office.12%29.aspx) and [there](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms694353%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Your question is not actually about COM itself, you need documentation for this specific COM object (MS Word Automation), for its COM interface.

Comment: May be I should search specificaly for this COM object. But still I have no idea why the line `:= wdColorBlue := 16711680` should be mentioned as it is instead `:= 16711680` or `:= wdColorBlue`. Probably I won't have luck to have answer immediately

Comment: Start with the [manual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838565.aspx).  Microsoft's developer network describes the Word object model in detail.

Comment: @destination-data certainly I will

Comment: One good way to get this information, especially the numeric values of Enums, is to look in Word's "Object Browser" (F2 from within the VBA IDE, which you can open using Alt+f11 in the Word UI). Querying values in the VBA IDE Immediate Window (Ctrl+G) is also useful. Example: Type: ?wdColorBlue then press Enter

Comment: @CindyMeister: My confusion is not about what is the value of wdColorBlue. But why `:= wdColorBlue := 16711680` only works? why mentioning `:= wdColorBlue` didn't work? COM Documentation says adding object variable is enough. So we should be fine with adding only `:= wdColorBlue`. But as my above reference URL we should mention `:= wdColorBlue := 16711680`. I think my question is more clear now

Comment: OK I think I may follow what you're asking, now... wdColorBlue is a member of an Enumeration. Enumerations have a "namespace" within the Word object model. It might be, for example, Word.WdColor.wdColorBlue, where Word is not the Word Application object, but the reference to the Word DLL/"interop" namespace. In VBA there's no need to fully qualify the Enumeration, but in other languages, such as C#, the full qualification is required. You can also see the Enumeration "namespace" in the VBA IDE Object Browser, at the bottom, if you search wdColorBlue.

Comment: @CindyMeister: Aah. Now found out what you are trying to explain to me. I hope it would be a guide to me to learn further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Translating" Office object models from the native VBA to use in other language environments can be tricky. Reading code snippets in the other language is a good way to get started - to get a "feel" for how it looks.

One important aspect to notice is that in some languages it's necessary to *fully qualify* the "namespace" from which something comes. For an Enumeration such as wdColorBlue, for example, the "parent" Enumeration may be necessary, which would be something like WdColor. (Note that the "parent" Enumeration in Word will always start with `Wd`, the enumeration elements start with `wd`.)

And in some languages you might need to specify the object model namespace, such as Word. Other languages, such as C#, need both: `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdColor.wdColorBlue`. (Or, if a using statement has been defined, like `using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` then it would be `Word.WdColor.wdColorBlue`.)

When it comes to researching and using parts of the object model that aren't in code snippets, the VBA IDE does provide some tools that compliment what you can glean from the official Language References.

- **Object Browser** The VBA IDE Object Browser can be accessed using F2 in the IDE (Alt+F11 to get to the IDE from within an Office application). Type the term you want to look at into the "Find" box and you'll get a list of corresponding object model elements. Clicking on an element brings up more information in the window below. At the very bottom is a gray section with additional details. For example, the "parent" Enumeration namespace for an Enum member such as wdColorBlue. Or a method's signature. (If you ever notice a conflict between Language Reference information and what you see in the Object Browser, the content of the Object Browser is correct!)
- **Immediate Window**. You can also query information using the VBA IDE Immediate Window (Ctrlf+G). Type a question mark (?) followed by the term - wdColorBlue, for example - press ENTER and the Enum integer value will be displayed. There's also Intellisense while typing in the Immediate Window.